# GMSVisibleRegion excluding padding - Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

As per the documentation the Google logo should be positioned using `GMSMapView` padding insets.

However this means that `GMSVisibleRegion` and then subsequently `GMSCoordinateBounds` don't encompass the entire visible screen (and all the visible markers).

Is there is a way to get `GMSVisibleRegion` and then subsequently `GMSCoordinateBounds` to include the whole screen area EXCLUDING the padding?